# Find params in most consuming sql queries (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

In my RDS postgres db,  I'm able to identify most CPU consuming/called queries by

```
select 
(total_exec_time / 1000 / 3600) as total_hours,
(total_exec_time / 1000) as total_seconds,
(total_exec_time / calls) as avg_millis, 
calls num_calls,
query 
from pg_stat_statements 
order by 1 desc limit 15;
```

But it returns me queries full of params $1, $2 and so on..
I definitely need to see these parameters.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot see these parameters in `pg_stat_statements` because that module only tracks execution statistics, no information about individual query executions.

If the queries run sufficiently long, you should set `log_min_duration_statement` to a time shorter than that. Then you can find individual executions of the statement with all the parameter values in the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  
Unfortunately the query has avg 2ms but is called 1,006,781,966 times..
So it means it would start to log almost every query, which might get even worse CPU load which is near the max now.
Maybe set it for some very short time and then set off ?

Comment: @IvoBabinec-Leo if all the executions are too slow, then the parameters don't matter.  If only some are, then set the duration long enough to catch just those ones.

Comment: Select some possible values from the tables and see if you can reproduce the execution time with those. If the query is that fast, the solution could also be to use a prepared statement or to replace many such queries with a single one (write a join?).